# Excel Changing The Last Digit Of My Number To Zero

Tags: c#, excel, controller

In my case I create a **CSV** file using **StreamWriter** in c# using code below:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult createAllSubscribtionsExcelFile()
    {       
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["ID"]);
        long totalRecords;
        var Members = Services.MemberService.GetAll(0, int.MaxValue, out totalRecords);
        string baseURL = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"));
        string packageName = Umbraco.Content(ID).Name;
        string currentPath = Server.MapPath("/") + packageName;
        string returnPath = baseURL + "/" + packageName;
        string orderNumber = "none"; string price = "none"; string theBillNumber = "none";
        List<RootObject> packages = null;
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(currentPath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Create(currentPath);
        }
        using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(currentPath + ".csv", false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {              
            foreach (var member in Members)
            {
                var NestedPackages = member.GetValue<string>("packages");
                if (NestedPackages != null)
                {
                    packages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(NestedPackages);
                }

                if (NestedPackages != null)
                {
                    foreach (var package in packages)
                    {
                        var udi = package.package;
                        var content = Umbraco.Content(udi);
                        orderNumber = package.orderNumber;
                        price = package.theAmountPaid.ToString();
                        theBillNumber = package.theBillNumber;

                        sr.WriteLine("" + "," + orderNumber.Replace(',', ' ').Replace('/', ' ') + "," + price.Replace(',', ' ').Replace('/', ' ')
                            + "," + theBillNumber.Replace(',', ' ').Replace('/', ' '));
                    }
                }
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        return Redirect(returnPath + ".csv");
    }
```

In my case **theBillNumber = "16744817032020146676"**, but the value that shown in the excel sheet like that 
**"16744817032020100000"** (the last 5 digits Equuleus zero).

How can I fix this problem, Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tiny trick!

Using c# I create a `.CSV` with the single line:

```
12/25/2021,James,'1836542348674987512345363,12
```

Note the **single quote** at the start of the really big number.

If we do not pre-pend a text character, Excel will treat the number as a super big integer with way more than 15 decimal digits.  Excel will automatically convert the trailing numerals into zeros.  The single quote tells Excel to leave all the numerals alone.

Once Excel opens the `.CSV` normally, all the numerals are present, but the cell begins with the single quote.  The following VBA will open the `.CSV` and convert any leading single quote into a PrefixCharacter.

Then using Excel VBA:

```
Sub dural()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\garys\Desktop\x.csv"

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        v = cell.Value
        If Left(v, 1) = "'" Then
            cell.Clear
            cell.NumberFormat = "@"
            cell.Value = v
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I get:

[image]

As you see by comparing the value in the Formula Bar to the value in the cell, the single quote is no longer part of the number.  It is just a PrefixCharacter.

This kind of handling is useful for:

- long phone numbers
- USPS tracking numbers
- banking account and routing numbers
- etc.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I need the code in c# not in VB please.

Comment: @PortlandRunner  Only converting values in which the first character is a single quote that is `ASCII 39`

Comment: @PortlandRunner I will add to my explanation

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, and I hadn't found a solution for it, I had to add an underscore before the number so it would be treated as text

Answer (score 0):

As documented on the Microsoft Learn website, large numbers (lengths greater than 15 digits) are automatically converted to zeroes.

Hence as a workaround, prefix such large digits with a single quote.

[Last digits are changed to zeros when you type long numbers in cells of Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/last-digits-changed-to-zeros)